# facebook og metas not working

Tags: facebook, debugging, meta-tags

Im trying to set my og meta tags on my website: www.smokebuddies.com.br

Everything seems to be ok:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Smoke Buddies -Tudo sobre Maconha">
<meta property="og:description" content="O Smoke Buddies é um site de conteúdo jornalístico especializado em informações sobre maconha, em conformidade com a lei">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://smokebuddies.com.br/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Smoke Buddies">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://smokebuddies.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/sb_fb.jpg">
```

But im still getting errors on facebook og debugger:

**The object in the URL ' http://smokebuddies.com.br/ ' type ' website ' is invalid because a required property ' og : title ' of type ' string ' is not provided .**

**Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received**

When i try to paste the website url on my facebook timeline, it remains blank...
Can someone help me please?

Comment: The second message is the relevant one here - your site takes too long to respond, so Facebook cancels it after ten seconds.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, I'm seeing the og:title tag in your markup however the debugger isn't picking it up. Probably should consider creating a page with just the tags (no content) and see if you can get deeper to the issue.

This is how it appears in my composer

[image: No preview image shown]

Otherwise submit a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs